# Registering custom made plugin into custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I made a custom plugin which contains some meta boxes which I want to implement in a custom post type, but I can not find any documentation on that on the web.

This is my function for registering custom post type.

```
   function models_post_type() {
    $labels = array (
        'name'                  => _x( 'Models', 'Post Type General Name', 'basicmodels' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Model', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'basicmodels' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Models', 'basicmodels' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Model', 'basicmodels' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Models', 'basicmodels' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Model', 'basicmodels' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Model', 'basicmodels' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'basicmodels' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Model', 'basicmodels' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update model', 'basicmodels' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Model', 'basicmodels' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Model Not Found', 'basicmodels' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not Found In Trash', 'basicmodels' ),
    );

    $args = array (
        'label'                 => __( 'Models', 'basicmodels' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Lista modela i informacije', 'basicmodels' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );

    register_post_type( 'models', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'models_post_type' );
```

And my plugin is working perfectly, so I think I do not need to post code. What should I add in `'supports'` to implement my plugin in my post type?

I've tried adding `'custom-fields'` into `supports`, but I get a lot of custom fields and not my plugin.

Comment: Meta boxes are displayed based on their post types eg posts, pages, products or your custom post type. If the register_post_type  works i think it should work, and problem is in the add post meta function. What code you use for meta boxes?

Comment: You were right, thank you. I had to change arguments in `register_post_type` function and now it's working. Thank you so much!

Comment: You mean the `screen` argument on your `add_meta_box` function?

Comment: No. I had invalid argument in `register_post_type`. It was `register_post_type( 'modelinfos', $args );` and it should be `register_post_type( 'models', $args );`. So, I just changed it and it worked. Got a bit confused, but everything is fine now.

Comment: Oh the typos are real today lol xd glad you found it!

Comment: Well, this is my first typo for 10 days since I sailed into WordPress. I never ever worked with it and I am already writing some plugin. At first, it was so confusing, but now it's easier. I would never find this typo without you. Thanks for saving my time! xD

Comment: Haha not personally ment, but today many typos are made xd by others also, anyway, really nice to hear you jumped into wordpress, i build everything in wordpress these days xd ez pz lemmon sqeezy. Keep it up. Ps. 10 days and already writing a plugin is pretty sweet ;)